How to connect to GraphQL server using graphql-ws
I'm working on an internal scrapping service (don't ask me why...) and can't figure out how to connect to the graphql query.
When I inspect the page's network tab I see that the URL it connects to is wss://website.com/server/query?apiKey=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
The websocket also send an authentication message and then a "subscribe" message.
If I use normal websockets / Postman I can connect to the URL and send the authentication message but if I try to send the subscribe message I get Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 1006
I am trying to use graphql-ws instead of raw websocket but my example is not working:
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const { createClient } = require('graphql-ws')

const client = createClient({
  webSocketImpl: WebSocket,
  url: `wss://website.com/server/query?apiKey=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX`,
  connectionParams: async () => {
    return {
      "X-Api-Key":"XXX-XXX-XXX",
      "X-Locale":"EN",
    }
  },
  lazy: false,
  on: {
    connected: () => {
      console.log(`GRAPHQL-WS CONNECTED`);
    },
  },
})

const payload = {
  extensions: {},
  variables: {
    memberId: "1234"
  },
  operationName: "onUpdate",
  query: `subscription onUpdate($memberId: ID!) {
    onUpdate(memberId: $memberId, withInit: true) {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
      __typename
    }
  }`
};

function executeQuery() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result;
    client.subscribe(
      payload,
      {
        next: (data) => {
          result = data;
        },
        error: (err) => reject(err),
        complete: () => resolve(result),
      }
    );
  });
}

// Execute the query and handle the result
executeQuery()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('Query result:', result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error executing query:', error);
  });


I get the log for GRAPHQL-WS CONNECTED but never any events, and the socket keeps reconnecting because I get multiple GRAPHQL-WS CONNECTED messages
